# Javascript to control scroll of the webpage is not working

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to create a submenu that pops from the side of the webpage. What I'm trying to achieve is that when the submenu is open, the scroll has to be disabled. I am written the below javascript for the same. For some reason, it is not working. Can anyone point out why.

Ps. the same code is working on another webpage of mine.

```js
const USERINFO = document.getElementById("USERINFO");
const subMenu = document.getElementById("login-subMenu");
const closeButton = document.getElementById("closeButton");
const html = document.documentElement;


  html.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target !== USERINFO) {
      subMenu.style.right = "-445px";
      html.classList.remove("dimmed");
      document.body.style.overflow = 'auto'; // added this line
    } else {
      document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'; // added this line
    }
  });


subMenu.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<div id="right_nav">
  <a id="USERINFO"> Help ></a>
</div>


<div id="login-subMenu">
  <button id="closeButton">Close X</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Never toggle scrollbars. Such will cause a shift in the document elements flow, cause recalculation, repaint etc.
PS, avoid changing `style` (unless strictly necessary). I.e: `document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';` is not needed, you already use the `.dimmed` in CSS. Besides you're forgetting to re-add that class using `html.classList.add("dimmed");`, you can handle it all within CSS. Also, never toggle that way scrollbars since this will trigger ~17px of widths change, document reflow, repaint etc.

Comment: PS, `>` (in `"Help >"`) is a special character in HTML as you know already. Use instead `&gt;` or `&lt;` in HTML to represent those angled brackets. Also, don't use anchors `<a>` (used to navigate) - if what you actually need is a `<button>`.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid changing `style` from JS (unless in the super rare cases when strictly necessary). `document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';` is not needed, you already use the `.dimmed` in CSS. Besides you're forgetting to re-add that class using `html.classList.add("dimmed");`, you can handle it all within CSS.

Simply store the class you want to toggle in the HTML element inside a `data-toggle-class` attribute.

```js
const elHtml = document.documentElement;

elHtml.addEventListener("click", (evt) => {
  const elBtn = evt.target.closest("[data-toggle-class]");
  if (!elBtn) return; 
  elHtml.classList.toggle(elBtn.dataset.toggleClass);
});
```

```css
* {margin:0; box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  min-height: 300vh; /* Just some demo scrollbars */
}

#login-subMenu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100dvh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: gold;
  transition: translate 0.5s;
  translate: -100% 0%;
}

/* Dynamic HTML classes */
.is-subMenu                { overflow: hidden; }
.is-subMenu #login-subMenu { translate: 0% 0%; }
.is-dark * { background: #000; color: #fff; }
```

```html
<div id="right_nav">
  <button type="button" data-toggle-class="is-subMenu">Help</button>
  <button type="button" data-toggle-class="is-dark">Theme</button>
</div>

<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex aspernatur, sunt tempore. Laboriosam ratione aliquid harum assumenda deserunt, perspiciatis nulla nobis, suscipit itaque quidem? Ex, sequi, laboriosam. Numquam explicabo, quo.
</p>

<div id="login-subMenu">
  <button type="button" data-toggle-class="is-subMenu">Close &#x2715;</button>
</div>
```

PS: the idea to toggle the main app's scrollbars should be highly discouraged anyways. Such will cause sudden elements expanding, browser reflow, repaint etc. which, when using animations for the menu (which is the de-facto standard) results in a pretty ugly UI/UX.